# Clear "Other Volumes" storage in Disk Utility

Tags: macos, high-sierra, disk-utility

I have around 7 GB of stuff labeled under Other Volumes in my disk. What is using the storage reported under **Other Volumes** in Disk Utility and how to remove it?

I am running macOS High Sierra.

Comment: I wouldn't pay much attention to the other category.    It often mis-reported.  If you need to free up some disk space, Run
OmniDiskSweeper
"The simple, fast way to save disk space"
OmniDiskSweeper is now free!
http://www.omnigroup.com/applications/omnidisksweeper/download/

Answer (score 1):

**No**, you can't remove it.

Along with the startup volume on which the macOS is installed, there are additional volumes which are created and used by your Mac. These other volume(s) are hidden and some of them are not even mounted.

To list the volumes, run:

`diskutil list`

The occupied storage space of all such hidden volumes is aggregated and reported under **Other Volumes** in Disk Utility.

Comment: The storage is on the startup drive.  It doesn't count hidden partitions.